# Android, InstallException occurs when I use in-app updates

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-update, google-play-core

In Google I/O 2019, In-app update is added newly.

So I am trying to use it following the document: https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle/in-app-updates

But it sent an InstallException like:

```
com.google.android.play.core.tasks.RuntimeExecutionException: com.google.android.play.core.install.InstallException: Install Error: -6
    at com.google.android.play.core.tasks.k.getResult(Unknown Source:18)
    at com.eastriver.workingtimer.ui.MainActivity$onCreate$1.onComplete(MainActivity.kt:35)
```

And my code is here:

```
val appUpdateManager = AppUpdateManagerFactory.create(this)
val appUpdateInfo = appUpdateManager.appUpdateInfo
appUpdateInfo.addOnCompleteListener {
    val result = it.result
    if (result.updateAvailability() == UpdateAvailability.UPDATE_AVAILABLE
                    && result.isUpdateTypeAllowed(AppUpdateType.FLEXIBLE)) {

        info("should show update")
        appUpdateManager.startUpdateFlowForResult(
            result,
            AppUpdateType.FLEXIBLE,
            this,
            1)
    } else {
        info("This is already latest version!")
    }
}
```

I know, it is released just nowadays.
But somebody knows this?

Comment: interesting. I'm getting this error instead:

`ERROR_API_NOT_AVAILABLE
int ERROR_API_NOT_AVAILABLE
The API is not available on this device.

Constant Value: -3 (0xfffffffd)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error codes are documented in [the javadoc](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/play/core/install/model/InstallErrorCode.html#error_install_not_allowed).

This says:

> int ERROR_INSTALL_NOT_ALLOWED
>
> The download/install is not allowed, due to the current device state (e.g. low
> battery, low disk space, ...).
>
> Constant Value: -6 (0xfffffffa)

So I suspect your device either does not have space or is not plugged in to power, and the update preferences on this device require power and WiFi.

Comment: Wow, I need this link! Thank you :)

Answer (score 9):

If you are working on the emulator, make sure you have Google Play Store installed and signed in.

Comment: Thanks, this was the source of my issue.

Comment: Ok, and any snippets on how to do this?